# QR Code is not staying on screen after button is released

Tags: html, css, qr-code

I followed an online tutorial to create a qr code generator.  While the code works and I am able to display the image, I am unable to get the image to stay on screen after the button is released.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style2.css">
    <style>
        .container.active .qr-code {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
        <p>Type a URL or text to generate a QR Code</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-form">
        <input type="text" class="qr-input" placeholder="Enter URL or text">
        <button class="generate-btn">Generate QR Code</button> 
    </div>
    <div class="qr-code">
        <img class="qr-image" alt="">
    </div>
   </div>

<script>
    var container = document.querySelector(".container");
    var generateBtn = document.querySelector(".generate-btn");
    var qrInput = document.querySelector(".qr-input");
    var qrImg = document.querySelector(".qr-image");

    generateBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if (qrInput.value.length > 0) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
            container.classList.add("active");
            var qrUrl = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + encodeURIComponent(qrInput.value);
            qrImg.src = qrUrl;
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>


CSS:

* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins';
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #ff676d;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}   

.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    transition: .1s;
}

.header h1{
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input, button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
    border: none;
    background-color: #1d68d8;
    font-size: 15px;
    columns: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input {
    border: 1px solid #8b8a8a;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.qr-code { 
    padding: 25px 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .5s;
}

.container:active {
    height: 490px;
}

.container:active .qr-code {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Very new to this, I have tried to adjust the display property in the css qr-code section, but having done some reading in to this I don't think that is correct.

Possibly I am not looking into the html correctly.

Comment: Opacity 0 means hide, 1 means show. the javascript in the button adds the CSS named active that changes the opacity

Answer (score 0):

You have confused two things.

:active is a CSS pseudo class - it is set while the user is 'pressing' the button and cleared when they 'release' it.

In your stylesheet you have the opacity setting to 1 while :active.

However, in your Javascript you have added the class called active to the element.

To make your stylesheet notice this rather than the pseudo class you need to use .active.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ff676d;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 400px;
  transition: .1s;
}

.header h1 {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.header p {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input,
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background-color: #1d68d8;
  font-size: 15px;
  columns: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #8b8a8a;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.qr-code {
  padding: 25px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: .5s;
}

.container.active {
  height: 490px;
}

.container.active .qr-code {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style2.css">
  <style>
    .container.active .qr-code {
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
      <p>Type a URL or text to generate a QR Code</p>
    </div>
    <div class="input-form">
      <input type="text" class="qr-input" placeholder="Enter URL or text">
      <button class="generate-btn">Generate QR Code</button>
    </div>
    <div class="qr-code">
      <img class="qr-image" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var container = document.querySelector(".container");
    var generateBtn = document.querySelector(".generate-btn");
    var qrInput = document.querySelector(".qr-input");
    var qrImg = document.querySelector(".qr-image");

    generateBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if (qrInput.value.length > 0) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
        container.classList.add("active");
        var qrUrl = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=" + encodeURIComponent(qrInput.value);
        qrImg.src = qrUrl;
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can read about the :active pseudo class at [MDN](http://www.devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:active.html#:%7E:text=The%20%3Aactive%20CSS%20pseudo-class%20represents%20an%20element%20%28such,but%20may%20be%20used%20on%20other%20elements%2C%20too.)